# gentoo sshd not work

Tags: linux, ssh, gentoo, remote-control

I build gentoo 3 days ago, and I installed openssh.
When I run the command `/etc/init.d/sshd start`,
and the bash varible `$?` is 0, as it suggestes nothing went wrong.
But I can't find a sshd's pid by using the command `ps -e |grep ssh`.
And the file `/var/run/sshd.pid` does not exists either.

When I try this command `ssh localhost`,it refuse me because port 22 is not using.

Comment: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH - that will refer you to the man page which will imply (or even state directly) that you need to generate keys. http://whattheit.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linux-generate-or-regenerate-host-keys-for-sshd/

Comment: You can try to start sshd from the command line in debug mode `sshd -d` (as root), which can help you to narrow down the problem.